# Assigning Pods to different nodepools with NodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes, devops, affinity

I am trying to assign a cluster of pods to nodepools and I would like those nodepools to change based on the resources requested by the cluster pods. However, I'd like the pods to prefer the smaller of the nodepools (worker) and ignore the larger nodes (lgworker) (so, do not trigger a scale up).

```yaml
        extraPodConfig:
          tolerations:
            - key: toleration_label
              value: worker
              operator: Equal
          affinity:
            nodeAffinity:
              requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                  - key: a_node_selector_label
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - worker
              preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                - weight: 100
                  preference:
                    matchExpressions:
                    - key: node_label
                      operator: In
                      values: 
                      - worker
                - weight: 90
                  preference:
                    matchExpressions:
                    - key: node_label
                      operator: In
                      values: 
                      - lgworker
```

The cluster pods default resource requests will fit on the smaller nodes easily and so I want to cause that to be used first. The larger nodepool should only be triggered when more resources than would fit on the smaller node be requested.

I have tried to weight the preferences, however the default cluster pods are being scheduled on to the larger nodepool.

Is there something I am missing that would help me properly assign pods to the smaller nodes over the larger nodes?

Comment: Which Kubernetes verision are you using? The behaviour may differ in the different versions. Are you using any [requests or limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) in your pod / deployment definition? Are you sure that smaller nodes have available resources?

Comment: K8s version is 1.21. This is through the daskhub helm chart, which are limits. Also, yes, the pods fit on the smaller nodes (three pods per node at the default limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using appropriate weighting helps to prefer the correct node, however, when enough Dask workers are requested, a number of those workers may end up on the `lgworker` nodes. The fix to this would be to update the `kube-scheduler` to consider 100% of nodes when considering scheduling. By default the `kube-scheduler` will consider [N% (dynamically determined)](https://v1-21.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduler-perf-tuning/#default-threshold) of nodes at a time to evaluate by filtering and scoring [v1.21.Kube-Scheduler](https://v1-21.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/).

NodeAffinity will only go so far and due to it's non-guarantee of enforcing affinities, this could cause pods to be scheduled on unpreferred nodes.

[Node Affinity v1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#nodeaffinity-v1-core) :

> The scheduler will prefer to schedule pods to nodes that satisfy the affinity expressions specified by this field, but it may choose a node that violates one or more of the expressions. The node that is most preferred is the one with the greatest sum of weights, i.e. for each node that meets all of the scheduling requirements (resource request, requiredDuringScheduling affinity expressions, etc.), compute a sum by iterating through the elements of this field and adding "weight" to the sum if the node matches the corresponding matchExpressions; the node(s) with the highest sum are the most preferred.

```yaml
        extraPodConfig:
          tolerations:
            - key: node_toleration
              value: worker
              operator: Equal
          affinity:
            nodeAffinity:
              requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                  - key: node_label
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - worker
                      - lgworker
              preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                - weight: 100
                  preference:
                    matchExpressions:
                    - key: node_label
                      operator: In
                      values: 
                      - worker
                - weight: 1
                  preference:
                    matchExpressions:
                    - key: node_label
                      operator: In
                      values: 
                      - lgworker
```

So, affecting the `kube-scheduler` would involve updating its configuration:
[Example](https://v1-21.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduler-perf-tuning/#example)

```yaml
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
algorithmSource:
  provider: DefaultProvider

...

percentageOfNodesToScore: 100
```